# CollectionView in Nib doesn't have cells?

Tags: swift, tableview, collectionview, nib

I'm building my app like that: one ViewController = one nib file etc.

But when I added collection view in my view controller for some reason I can't add cells to it, what is the problem?

Also when I drag the cell to this collection view nothing happens...

Same problem with TableView...

[image: CollectionView in interface builder]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Nibs don't support adding cells to collection views or table views directly in the nib. Only storyboards do. To use a nib with a collection/table view in it, you would have to programmatically register your cell class (or cell nib) with the collection/table view.